# Error - AJAX events should be attached to document: ajaxComplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to **Ajax** and my browser is giving me an error:

> "JQMIGRATE: AJAX events should be attached to document: ajaxComplete"

I think I have to add the following **Ajax** functions below for it to work properly, but not sure where they would go in my **Ajax** **POST** code. Could someone help me resolve this error by letting me know how and where to add these functions?

Edited...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cash Drawer AJAX Interface</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){   
            $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
                 console.log('Ajax request started !');
            });
            $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
                 console.log('Ajax request ended !')
            });
            $(document).ajaxComplete(function() { $( ".log" ).text( "Ajax    request completed" ); });          
            $('#kickDrawer').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log('Client drawer kick clicked');
                var data = {};
                data.title = "title";
                data.message = "message";
                // Drawer kick post                 
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    url: 'http://localhost:4444/kickCashDrawer',                        
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log('success');
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    },
                    error  : function() { console.log('error');}
                });
            });             
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="kickDrawer">
    <input type="button" value="Kick Drawer" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That error has nothing to do with your code. What other code is running on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is javascript it should be included inside the `script` tags for it to be parsed.

Just include them inside the `document ready` handler.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {      
            $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
                 console.log('Ajax request started !');
            });
            $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
                 console.log('Ajax request ended !')
            }); 

            $('#clientRequest').click(function(e){
            .....
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks guys. My AJAX post call works on my local machine with no errors, but when I use this script server side in an AJAX widget which is part of our server software, it must be more particular about what format it needs. I added the start and stop functions per your example, but I think I also need the $( document ).ajaxComplete() function too since that's the error being reported from our server application in the console output. So could you let me know how this function can be integrated in?

Thanks so much!

Comment: @Wildview Just include `$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $( ".log" ).text( "Ajax request completed" );
});` as part of the change

Comment: I edited the code above, is this how the functions are integrated since I still get an error in the console window that says "AJAX events should be attached to document: ajaxComplete" Could you let me know? 

Thanks again for your quick responses.